# CSS DIV using percentages

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

So I got this fiddle:  http://jsfiddle.net/69WVx/3/

I have also attached the code.  Basically, I want test2 and test3 to be inline with one another.  I also want the widths of test2 and test3 to be %, as it's for a mobile responsive button.

Can this be done the way I'm doing it? Or am I screwing this all up?

As you can see, the DIV's test2 and test3 collapse on top of one another, as opposed to being inline.

HTML:

```
<div class="test">
    <div class="test1">
        <div class="test2">ORANGE</div>
        <div class="test3">APPLE</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.test {
    position: relative;
    width: 300px;
    height: 100px;
    border: 1px solid #FF0000;
}
.test1 {
    width: 90%;
    height: 50%;
    border: 1px solid;
    position: relative;
}
.test2 {
    width: 40%;
    border: 1px solid #00FF00;
    display: inline;
    position: absolute;
}
.test3 {
    width: 40%;
    border: 1px solid;
    display: inline;
    position: absolute;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this , Trying my best to help .

Don't know if this is what you want. ***[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/69WVx/10/)***

If you want to keep position absolute do the following

```
.test2 {
    width: 40%;
    border: 1px solid #00FF00;
    display: inline-block;
  position :absolute;
}
.test3 {
    width: 40%;
    border: 1px solid;
    display: inline-block;
    position :absolute;
    margin-left:40%;
    }
```

***Or*** Even this will do

```
.test2 {
    width: 40%;
    border: 1px solid #00FF00;
    display: inline-block;
}
.test3 {
    width: 40%;
    border: 1px solid;
    display: inline-block;
```

}

Comment: Glad to have helped you. :) If it helps, you can mark it as answer :)

Answer (score 0):

The `position:absolute` properties in your CSS were causing both `.test2` and `.test3` to display on top of one another.  Removing that property from both elements provides the inline appearance you're looking for.

Also, as Jc. points out below, the `display` properties should be set to `inline-block` instead of `inline`

```
.test2 {
    width: 60%;
    border: 1px solid #00FF00;
    display: inline-block;
} 
.test3 {
    width: 30%;
    border: 1px solid;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/69WVx/11/

Comment: hmm, but if I do that, then setting the widths as % for test2 and test3 doesn't work anymore.  I just tried it.

Comment: good point - updated answer to include `display: inline-block`

Answer (score 0):

Apply `display: inline-block;` for the inner blocks such as **.test2** and **.test3**, so that you can achieve this..

Check this [**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/69WVx/9/)...

**CSS:**

```
.test {
    position: relative;
    width: 300px;
    height: 100px;
    border: 1px solid #FF0000;
}
.test1 {
    width: 90%;
    height: 50%;
    border: 1px solid;
    position: relative;
}
.test2 {
    width: 40%;
    border: 1px solid #00FF00;
    display: inline-block;
}
.test3 {
    width: 40%;
    border: 1px solid;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/69WVx/6/)

Your mistake is:

1.You let `.test2`&`.test3`  position:absolute,this will  cause them to be deleted from the normal flow.If you don't define the top,left,right,bottom of the elements,they will cover each other of course.However,you don't have the need to use "position" here.

2.Div should be displayed inline-block. Inline elements **do not** have width or height properties.So you can see though you let the divs `width:40%` ,it doesn't work. Let them `display:inline-block;`

Answer (score 0):

Well here is what i tried i guess this is what u want ...

HTML :

```
<div class="test">
    <div class="test1">
        <div class="test2">ORANGE</div>
        <div class="test3">APPLE</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS :

```
.test {
    position: relative;
    width: 300px;
    height: 100px;
    border: 1px solid #FF0000;
}
.test1 {
    width: 90%;
    height: 50%;
    border: 1px solid;
    position: relative;
}
.test2 {
    width: 40%;
    border: 1px solid #00FF00;
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
}
.test3 {
    width: 40%;
    border: 1px solid;
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
}
```

here is the fiddle ----> [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/GSr6w/)

Well the reason why it overlapped was because you have positioned it absolute ...... either give relative positioning or provide the positioning for an absolute layout in order to get what you wanted ....